# Help needed for creating project network diagram from WBS

Tags: work-breakdown-structure, project-management-style

New Facility Center:  Work Breakdown Structure

Here below is the wbs... need to create network table and diagram from it..

Did I required to select major dependencies only for network table and diagram>

1.1 **Requirements**

1.1.1   **Locations identification**
1.1.1.1 Customer Base Analysis
1.1.1.2 Physical Structure Evaluation

1.2.    **Building Selection**

1.2.1.      Lease New Building
1.2.2.      Facility Access Agreement

1.3.    **Construction Build Out**
1.3.1   **Interior**
1.3.1.1 Secure Offices/Rooms
1.3.1.2 Customer Service Area
1.3.1.3 Employee Area
1.3.1.4 Secure Storeroom
1.3.1.5 Reception Area

1.3.2   **Exterior**

1.3.2.1.    Veranda
1.3.2.2.    Parking

1.3.3.  **Utilities**
1.3.3.1.    Electrical
1.3.3.2.    Gas
1.3.3.3.    Water
1.3.3.4.    Sewer

1.4.    **Facility Center Design**

1.4.1.  **Security System Installation**
1.4.1.1.    Key Card Access
1.4.1.2.    Physical Security
1.4.1.3.    Alarms
1.4.2.  **Interior**

1.4.2.1.    Architectural Drawings

1.4.2.2.    Lighting

1.4.2.3.    Furnishings

1.4.2.4.    Art

1.4.2.5.    Paint / Color Schemes

1.4.2.6.    Floor Space / In Store Displays

1.4.2.7.    Window Displays

1.4.3.  **Exterior**

1.4.3.1.    Architectural Drawings

1.4.3.2.    Lighting

1.4.3.3.    Signage

1.4.3.4.    Landscaping

1.4.3.5.    Parking

1.5.    **Communications Equipment/Network**

1.5.1.  **Equipment Purchase and Acquisition**
1.5.1.1.    Computer Systems
1.5.1.2.    Phone Systems
1.5.1.3.    Projectors
1.5.1.4.    Kiosk Machines
1.5.2.  **Communications Network Build out**
1.5.2.1.    Cabling
1.5.2.2.    Internet connectivity
1.5.2.3.    Phone system
1.5.2.4.    New equipment implementation
1.6.    **Quality review**
1.6.1.  Code compliance
1.6.2.  Construction
1.6.3.  Electrical
1.6.4.  Occupancy certificate

1.7.    **Center Maintenance**
1.7.1.  Housekeeping
1.7.2.  Insurance

Comment: Please improve the [formatting](http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) of your post. In addition, your post is unclear. What's your actual question?

Comment: It seems you are asking for someone here to produce a network diagram from your WBS. However, you do not have the information you need to produce a network diagram (you need dependencies and durations which you do not seem to have)

Answer (score 1):

Your network diagram is a result of when you schedule work to occur.  It is not just major dependencies.  You need to sequence logically based on both hard and soft dependencies, all of them, not just major.  Hard dependencies are dictated by task and resource constraints while soft dependencies are choices you make.  Either way, each package needs to have a predecessor(s) and successor(s).